# Sharepoint Calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a requirement of calculated field which maintains the log history. If it's a new document the field will contain the current date follwed by the name of the user who created the document and if the document gets edited the field will contain the user name who modified the item. Can somebody help me out!!?

Answer (score 1):

If the Modified date is the same as the Created date it is a New document

```
=IF( [Modified]=[Created] , "new" , "existing" )
```

#### Today

You can not get the Current (Today) date in a Calculated Column because (unlike Excel) the Formula is only updated when the Item is updated.

#### Username

You can not get the Username in a Calculated Column because the information is a Lookup to another (internal) list, Calculated Column Formulas can only access properties of the current item (I presume becuase of performance reasons)

Just display the Modified By column in your View, it will display the correct name for what you describe.

Comment: Wouldn't he be able to include the value from the `Editor` column?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF( [Modified]=[Created] , Me&" - "&TEXT(Today,"dd-mm-yyyy") ,Me)
```

For more information on calculated fields: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx